# boost context class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-context

I found boost has a class called context which is used for context switching, right?

I try to Google it but did not found any document or example. I am just wondering if anyone can provide some information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boost::Context is an official part of Boost in version 1.51.0 and up. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html for information about it. Unfortunately the documentation is *slightly* different than the implementation, and some things have changed in SVN, so you'll need to read the header files a little bit.

Here is an example I wrote the other day showing Boost::Context to make simple coroutines using Boost 1.51.0+latest SVN:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/context/all.hpp>

class Coroutine {
    public:
    Coroutine() :
        my_context(boost::context::make_fcontext(
            stack.data() + stack.size(),
            stack.size(),
            Coroutine::dispatch
        ))
    {}
    virtual ~Coroutine() {}

    void operator()() {
        boost::context::jump_fcontext(&yield_context, my_context, reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this));
    }

    protected:
    void yield() {
        boost::context::jump_fcontext(my_context, &yield_context, 0);
    }

    virtual void call() = 0;

    private:
    static void dispatch(intptr_t coroutine_ptr) {
        Coroutine *coroutine = reinterpret_cast<Coroutine *>(coroutine_ptr);
        coroutine->call();
        while (true) coroutine->yield();
    }

    private:
    boost::context::fcontext_t *my_context;
    boost::context::fcontext_t yield_context;
    std::array<intptr_t, 64*1024> stack;
};

struct A : public Coroutine {
    void call() {
        std::cerr << "A went to the store one day.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "A was looking for groceries.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "A finally found what she was looking for.\n";
    }
};

struct B : public Coroutine {
    void call() {
        std::cerr << "B went to the store one day.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "B was looking for replacement tires.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "B didn't find anything at all.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "B went to another store.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "B got the tires installed there.\n";
    }
};

struct C : public Coroutine {
    void call() {
        std::cerr << "C went to the store one day.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "C was looking for USB drives.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "C found several with competitive pricing.\n";
        yield();
        std::cerr << "C couldn't decide which to buy, so gave up.\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cerr << "So, this is what happened.\n";
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    for (size_t i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        a();
        b();
        c();
    }
    std::cerr << "Then it all was done.\n";
}
```

Then compiling and running looks like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o coroutines coroutines.c++ -lboost_context
$ ./coroutines
So, this is what happened.
A went to the store one day.
B went to the store one day.
C went to the store one day.
A was looking for groceries.
B was looking for replacement tires.
C was looking for USB drives.
A finally found what she was looking for.
B didn't find anything at all.
C found several with competitive pricing.
B went to another store.
C couldn't decide which to buy, so gave up.
B got the tires installed there.
Then it all was done.
```

Comment: @Lucretiel It's a member of the class, right there in the code: `std::array<intptr_t, 64*1024> stack;` =)

Comment: Oh. I totally didn't see the scrollbars

Comment: What `while (true) ..`  in `dispatch` method is for ?

Comment: @Dfr that's for when/if your coroutine falls of the end of its call implementation.

Comment: That is a great example thanks...but do you know why the third argument is need to switch context ? (old_context_ptr, new_context, mysterious_int_arg)

Comment: Ok, I get how it's used for the dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

The [boost-coroutine](http://olk.bplaced.net/boost-coroutine.zip) archive on the author's [website](http://olk.bplaced.net/) contains some basic docs and examples for both coroutine, which builds on context, and context itself. You'll also find a fiber package on that website, which might be interesting at least as another use case.

Comment: Bummer. It works for me. Note that context including basic examples and docs is in boost trunk by now. If you don't wanna checkout via SVN, you can also browse it online [here](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/context/). Coroutine and fiber are not in trunk (yet) though.

Comment: BTW, it seems active development on coroutine and fiber happens at Oliver Kowalke's [git repository](http://gitorious.org/~k-oli/boost-dev/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you wjl for your example code. It helped me understand how boost context works and how boost coroutine is implemented by means of boost context. But your code didn't work as it was, so I modified it to be compiled on Windows. (didn't check if it works on Linux though)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <boost/context/all.hpp>

class Coroutine {
public:
  Coroutine() :
    my_context(boost::context::make_fcontext(
    stack.data() + stack.size(),
    stack.size(),
    Coroutine::dispatch
    ))
  {}
  virtual ~Coroutine() {}

  void operator()() {
    boost::context::jump_fcontext(&yield_context, my_context, reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this));
  }

protected:
  void yield() {
    boost::context::jump_fcontext(&my_context, yield_context, 0);
  }

  virtual void call() = 0;

private:
  static void dispatch(intptr_t coroutine_ptr) {
    Coroutine *coroutine = reinterpret_cast<Coroutine *>(coroutine_ptr);
    coroutine->call();
    while (true) coroutine->yield();
  }

private:
  boost::context::fcontext_t my_context;
  boost::context::fcontext_t yield_context;
  std::array<intptr_t, 64 * 1024> stack;
};

struct A : public Coroutine {
  void call() {
    std::cerr << "A went to the store one day.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "A was looking for groceries.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "A finally found what she was looking for.\n";
  }
};

struct B : public Coroutine {
  void call() {
    std::cerr << "B went to the store one day.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "B was looking for replacement tires.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "B didn't find anything at all.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "B went to another store.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "B got the tires installed there.\n";
  }
};

struct C : public Coroutine {
  void call() {
    std::cerr << "C went to the store one day.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "C was looking for USB drives.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "C found several with competitive pricing.\n";
    yield();
    std::cerr << "C couldn't decide which to buy, so gave up.\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cerr << "So, this is what happened.\n";
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    a();
    b();
    c();
  }
  std::cerr << "Then it all was done.\n";
}
```